# Is this simple (atomic) lock thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

Is this code threadsafe? Should I have volatile in the function sig? (ex: `void Unlock() volatile {v=0;}`) If it isn't how do i make this threadsafe?

```
class SimpleLock {
    std::atomic<int> v;
public:
    bool try_lock() { int z=0; return v.compare_exchange_strong(z, 1); }
    void lock() { while(try_lock()==false) std::this_thread::yield(); }
    void unlock() {v=0;}
};
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this is toy code and should not be used in any kind of real application. Performance will be terrible compared to proper locks. (As just one example, imagine if there is no other thread to yield to and a thread calling `lock` is runing in the same physical core as a thread that holds the lock. Ouch!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is thread-safe, although you could rename `Lock` to `TryLock` since you are not calling CAS in a loop until it succeeds. Traditionally `Lock` operations are supposed to block until the acquire succeeds.

Regarding `volatile`, [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) of `std::atomic` specify (about the `=` operator):

> Atomically assigns a value t to the atomic variable. Equivalent to store(desired).

Then about `store`:

> void store( T desired, memory_order = std::memory_order_seq_cst );

Then about `memory_order = std::memory_order_seq_cst`:

- No writes in the writer thread can be reordered after the atomic
  store
- No reads in the reader thread can be reordered before the atomic load.
- The synchronization is established between all atomic operations tagged std::memory_order_seq_cst. All threads using such atomic
  operation see the same order of memory accesses.

So no, you don't need `volatile` here. Additionally, `volatile` has weaker guarantees than the ones above (in fact, `volatile` is mostly useless in C++):

> Within a thread of execution, accesses (reads and writes) to all
>   volatile objects are guaranteed to not be reordered relative to each
>   other, but this order is not guaranteed to be observed by another
>   thread, since volatile access does not establish inter-thread
>   synchronization.

Comment: Correct. Now do you have any idea if it should be `bool TryLock() volatile` or not?

Comment: If you'd like to use this lock with the standard library it's even better to call them `bool try_lock()` and `void unlock()`.

Comment: Re: "volatile has weaker guarantees than the ones above". Indeed: it has no guarantees in standard C++. It's as useful as your compiler's documentation says it is.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That's a little exaggerated, did you mean to suffix with "with respect to multithreading"?

Comment: @GManNickG - thanks. I was only thinking of multithreading. :-(